# Возможно ли использование результата запроса select в вставке данных insert?

Tags: postgresql

У меня задача добавить несколько записей в таблицу, но при это одним из значением values должен быть id, который я могу могу получить из другой таблицы.
Это возможно будет произвести?
СУБД PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: CTE и RETURNING. Доступно ли в вашей версии - смотрите мануал.

Comment: Сделаю уточнение по задаче. Я пишу миграционный скрипт т.е. у меня нет информации о количестве добавляемых строк. Вначале, я получаю select запросом массив id-ков (20312, 20343, 23475...); Далее, мне нужно как-то в цикле прописать в insert каждый id-ник отдельно. Возможно ли сохранить массив id-ков, после чего перебрать его в insert. Вначале, я получаю select запросом массив id-ков (20312, 20343, 23475...); Далее, мне нужно как-то в цикле прописать в insert каждый id-ник отдельно. Возможно ли сохранить массив id-ков, после чего перебрать его в insert. –

Answer (score 0):

Да, возможно. Вы можете использовать в `values` подзапросы:

```
insert into tablename (column1, column2) values (
    'value for column1',
    (select id from anothertable where ...)
);
```

Такой подзапрос должен возвращать одну запись (иначе ошибка). Если подзапрос ничего не нашёл - будет подставлен `NULL`

Вы можете воспользоваться `insert .. select` запросом:

```
insert into tablename (column1, column2) 
select
    'value for column1',
    id
from tablename
--- какой угодно запрос в части select
```

Эта форма `insert` может вставлять множество строк за раз.

Comment: Сделаю уточнение по задаче. Я пишу миграционный скрипт т.е. у меня нет информации о количестве добавляемых строк. 
Вначале, я получаю select запросом массив id-ков (20312, 20343, 23475...);
Далее, мне нужно как-то в цикле прописать в insert каждый id-ник отдельно.

Возможно ли сохранить массив id-ков, после чего перебрать его в insert.
Вначале, я получаю select запросом массив id-ков (20312, 20343, 23475...);
Далее, мне нужно как-то в цикле прописать в insert каждый id-ник отдельно.

Возможно ли сохранить массив id-ков, после чего перебрать его в insert.

Comment: Вам подойдёт `insert .. select`. Напишите любой select который даст в результате нужные вам значения, затем допишите insert into в начале - всё, это строки будут записаны.

Comment: Возвращает ошибку:
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000

Comment: Судя по ошибке (мне угадывать запрос?) вы написали подзапрос в values, а не `insert .. select` синтаксис. Это два разных способа.

Comment: Запрос

insert into featureparams (id, featuregroup_id) values (nextval('hibernate_sequence'), (select g.postingtemplate_id from featureparams as p left join featuregroup as g on p.featuregroup_id = g.id 
where g.name = 'Ценовые характеристики'));

В values указан подзапрос т.к. в таблице два обязательных поля.

Comment: @МингиянБасанов Вы читайте, что Вам пишут, что ли... разжую - в Вашем запросе НЕ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ СЛОВА `VALUES`.

Comment: @Мелкий Вы б убрали первый пример из ответа - автор походу только путается... если жаль потраченного на его набор времени - дайте этот текст в конце, постскриптумом.

Comment: Проблема в том что мне нужно в одном insert вставлять два id-ника:
1) получаю из sequnce;
2) из другой таблицы.

Comment: `В values указан подзапрос т.к. в таблице два обязательных поля` - какая разница? Сделайте чтобы список в select совпадал со списком полей insert и всё. `insert into ... (field1, field2) select nextval(...), field from ...` - в чём проблема? Я специально продемонстрировал в ответе как записать, например, константу.

Comment: `insert into featureparams (featuregroup_id, contenttype, index, isfilterrequired, isinvolvedinpricing, isinvolvedinsorting, isrequired, name, visibility, id)
select g.id, 'DOUBLE', 2, 'true', 'false', 'true', 'true',
'Минимальное время до начала мероприятия (в часах)', p.visibility, nextval('hibernate_sequence')
from featureparams as p left join featuregroup as g on p.featuregroup_id = g.id
left join postingtemplate as t on g.postingtemplate_id = t.id
where g.name = 'Ценовые характеристики' and g.postingtemplate_id is not null;`
только запрос добавляет 111 записей, вместо 43.

Comment: Ошибка возникает если используешь nextval('hibernate_sequence'). Почему так происходит?

Comment: @Akina я все читаю,не надо мне ничего разжевывать. Если Вы что-то не можете объяснить, то не делайте этого.

Comment: `только запрос добавляет 111 записей, вместо 43` - значит ваш select вернул 111 строк.

Answer (score 0):

Добавил условие where isfilterequired = 'true'. Запрос возвращает 43 записи.